# Why do I not need to shutdown javafx.concurrent.Service

Tags: javafx, java.util.concurrent

`javafx.concurrent.Service` uses internally a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` to execute its Tasks. Instances of `ExecutorService` need to be shut down after usage. This does not seem to be the case for `javafx.concurrent.Service`. How and when does `javafx.concurrent.Service` shutdown its `ExecutorService` ?

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html), the threads it creates are daemon threads, which will not prevent application shutdown.

Comment: Actually, implementing classes do the shutdown in the finalize method. I see no reason anymore to shutdown an `ExecutorService` just for "cleaning up".

Comment: It's not recommended to rely on finalizers. See *Effective Java* (Joshua Bloch), *Item 7: Avoid Finalizers*

Comment: I know. I did not write that code ;)

Comment: So, don't use finalizers. Set an executor service on the `Service`, call `shutdown` on it in the `stop` method, and implement the tasks the service creates to handle interruption gracefully.

Comment: I dont use them. I was just thinking of using a `javafx.concurrent.Service` in favor to an `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` because this way I do not need to think about how to shutdown eventually. I think there was an misunderstanding, I meant  implementing classes of ExecutorService which I get via `Executors` factory methods.

Comment: *Set an executor service on the Service, call shutdown on it in the stop method, and implement the tasks the service creates to handle interruption gracefully.* Is this the way you should use `Service`? Im not so sure..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139155/discussion-between-kerner1000-and-james-d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your misunderstanding here comes from:

> Instances of `ExecutorService` need to be shut down after usage.

Calling [`shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) prevents an `ExecutorService` from accepting new tasks. You only need to do that if it makes sense to do so (e.g. you are trying to exit the application and want to make sure that any new tasks submitted during application exit are ignored. This might happen with a scheduled executor service, for example).

The related `shutdownNow()` will additionally attempt to interrupt any currently running threads. So if your tasks are implemented to accept interrupts gracefully, calling `shutdownNow()` gives those tasks the opportunity to perform any cleanup operations necessary (closing connections, etc).

In many use cases, however, there is no need to call either of these methods. If you are assured no further tasks will be submitted to the executor, `shutdown()` is unnecessary. If your tasks are not long-running, `shutdownNow()` is unnecessary. When the application attempts to exit, any existing tasks will complete (presumably reasonably quickly) and then the application can exit.

Note that if your executor service uses daemon threads, then when the application attempts to exit, those threads will not prevent application exit (they will be terminated, without interruption). So if your tasks are short-lived, require no cleanup, and can be safely terminated at any point, this is a viable strategy.

There is nothing special about `javafx.concurrent.Service` here: in some sense it is a wrapper for an `ExecutorService` that provides additional functionality for interacting with the FX Application Thread. Just note that the default executor service provided uses daemon threads, so as above, if your tasks need cleanup you would likely provide a different executor service and shut it down gracefully in the application's `stop()` method.